# How to properly run a local node app in production

Tags: javascript, node.js, local, production

I am building an installation that features a node app that is not connected to the internet and will run locally on a computer. I'm wondering what is the best way to run this node app in production? Can I simply run 'node index.js' and be good enough? Do I need to bundle the app in any certain way or use something like this: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/ ?

Since I'm not using node in a traditional hosted online environment, I'm wondering what the best practices are for running a local node app in production.

I should add:
I am using node to run a local server that renders my HTML frontend. I am also using the node app to communicate with Arduino via serial ports. Lastly, I am using socket.io to send data from my node app to the frontend.

Comment: I run a node app on a Raspberry Pi that does some home automation control.  I start it using [`forever`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) so that if it ever crashes, it will get automatically restarted.  And, to guard against any leaks in the system (memory, files, etc...), I have the app automatically exit at 4am each night and then forever restarts it automatically.  The app is also configured to start in the startup of the Raspberry Pi (for power outage recovery). You don't have to do it that way, but this app has been running for 5 years now.

Answer (score -1):

Whether or not the app is hosted in the cloud or locally does not actually change the required command to start the application, as far as I know.

Even if you were to deploy your application to a service like Heroku, for example, it would still run your start command (likely `npm start`) which would probably spin up your server using a `node <file>.js`.

Since you're just hosting it locally, yes, you would just start it up with `node <file>.js`. You said that it won't be connected to the internet so I'm assuming that no user would access the application's endpoints. If that's the case, then you're good to go. Otherwise, you may need to use a service such as **Ngrok** or **Vortex** to proxy any requests from outside your network to the port your app is running on in your own network.

One other thing to note is that if you want your app to restart whenever you make any code changes, consider using the **nodemon** package which can help you achieve that. But again, that package still runs a `node <file.js>` command.

Comment: So if I just need to worry about the app crashing in production, could I get away with using nodemon to restart the server or should I handle that with pm2?

Comment: You might want to look into pm2 but the way I see it, if you wrap your code in try-catch blocks (which should be done for good code) your app wont necessarily crash in production. However there can be other causes ofc so if you want to be safe, i would suggest going with pm2. Nodemon is mainly for development purposes although you might be able to configure it for automatic restart with some research.